# Can't communicate between options and background in webextensions in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-addons, webextension-storage

I'm building an extension for Microsoft Edge. I have an options page which saves some values to *localStorage* like that:

```
localStorage.setItem('xxx', document.getElementById("xxx").value);
```

And retrieves them in background script:

```
var value1 = localStorage.getItem('xxx');
```

Works perfectly fine in all browsers except for Edge. I have to close Edge, reopen it and only then it updates storage for *background.html*. I inspected *options.html* and *background.html* and found out that updating options storage won't affect background, which is strange because they have to share the same storage.

Is there some workaround for that issue?

Comment: Try to use "[Storage.setItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)" and the "[Storage.getItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)" method to set and get the value, more detail information, please check [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API):**It's recommended to use the Web Storage API (setItem, getItem, removeItem, key, length) to prevent the pitfalls associated with using plain objects as key-value stores.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've found a solution which works for me.
I use [chrome.storage.local](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage) instead of *localStorage* and get real-time options-background communication.

I set some value in *options.js*:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({xxx:document.getElementById('xxx').value});
```

And create listener in *background.js* to track real-time changes:

```
    chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {  
     for(var key in changes) {
      window[key] = changes[key].newValue;
     }
   });
```